# How to use ngResource inside a bind callback function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngresource

I have made a directive which bind a click event with the element. On click I want to use a factory which makes an ajax call. How do I achieve this ? My code looks like this

```
    angular.module('user')
        .directive('activityFeed', function(userFactory, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                userFactory.getActivities();
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    console.log("hello");
                    userFactory.getActivities();

                })
            }
        }
    })
```

First call which is outside the bind function works. Now when I click on the attribute it logs "hello" but it doesn't call `getActivities()`.

Comment: andular? You may want to fix that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.bind('click', function() {
    console.log("hello");
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        userFactory.getActivities();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. It worked. Can you tell me why do I need to update the bindings before using factory ?

Comment: Angular is unaware of the things you do inside your click handler. So I used `$scope.$apply()` to notify angular of the call to be made to the service.